# Sass mixin variable arguments error

Tags: css, sass, mixins

I'm experiencing an inconsistant error when using variable arguments.

There's a few mixins in the project which accept variable arguments. One of which is;

```
@mixin box-shadow($shadows...) {
  -moz-box-shadow: $shadows;
  -webkit-box-shadow: $shadows;
  box-shadow: $shadows;
}
```

As you can see it accepts variable arguments.
This works fine on all but a couple of machines at my place of work.

On the machines where it's not working, we get the following error;

> Invalid CSS after "...x-shadow ($args": expected ")", was "...) {"

We're all running the same version of SASS, *Sass 3.3.7 (Maptastic Maple)*

Is there anything other than the version of SASS which could be causing the error?
We're all using the exact same codebase whilst trying to resolve this issue.

Comment: I see you too took the example of the docs. http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#variable_arguments I think you will have to post a bit more of the current implementation to be able to point out a problem

Comment: Can you reproduce this error on minimal mixin  with the name that is guaranteed to be unique ?

Comment: @NicoO That is the mixin we're using.

Comment: Also are those errors persistent.

Comment: @JAre I've just tested it with the following;

`@mixin uniquemixinname($args...){
@debug $args;
}`

_"Also are those errors persistent"_
In what way? They are persistent on the machines having the issue, but are none existent elsewhere.

We still have the error

Comment: Double check to make sure that you are in fact compiling with Sass 3.3.  Variable arguments were a new feature in 3.2.  An older version of another application like Compass might be causing you to drop to an older version.

Comment: @cimmanon How do you do that? I assume it's different to `sass -v`

Comment: can you run "gem list --local" Find and uninstall old versions.

Comment: @JAre I've just ran that and removed 2 versions, 3.2.14 and 3.2.19

Comment: @JAre still have the issue by the way

Comment: You should make sure you don't have multiple sass installations or don't have also compass for example with older version of sass

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek I've already sorted that part _"I've just ran that and removed 2 versions, 3.2.14 and 3.2.19"_

Comment: Can you verify that the three dots following `$args` are three dots and not [an ellipsis character (…)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2026/index.htm). Slim chance, I know, but stranger things have happened to me.

Comment: @rockerest yep, they're definitely dots.

Comment: please execute `sass --trace path/to/your/file` and show us the output message

Comment: @AlexGuerrero Apologies for the delay in getting back to you. The output of sass --trace /path outputs the sass from my project. I can't however, run my sass like that as I wrote a ruby file so I could use shorthand include paths.

Answer (score 0):

Should be:

```
@mixin box-shadow($shadows) {
  -moz-box-shadow: $shadows;
  -webkit-box-shadow: $shadows;
  box-shadow: $shadows;
}
```

Your ellipsis looks to be causing issues.

In addition, you may want to consider utilizing a SASS Mixin library to do a lot of these common vendor prefix jobs for you. I use Bourbon - http://bourbon.io/

There are all sorts of other benefits there too, like functions to convert pixels to rems etc.

**UPDATE**

I just realised you're trying to use variable arguments. In that case, the syntax looks correct judging from the docs. Make sure you're using SASS 3.2+

http://chriseppstein.github.io/blog/2012/08/23/sass-3-2-is-released/

I am running SASS 3.3.6 and I do not get this error using your code.

I'd recommend using a Gemfile in your project and build from that. This would ensure that you really are using the correct gems and everyone is on the same setup.

My Gemfile that works with your code:

```
# Install these gems by running 'bundle install'.
# Install bundle from these instructions: http://bundler.io/

source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Using Compass Alpha release due to compatability with SASS 3.3+
gem 'sass', '3.3.6'
gem 'compass', '~> 1.0.0.alpha.19'
gem 'bourbon', '4.0.1'
gem 'neat', '1.6.0'
```